# How to avoid redundancy in my database model?

Tags: mysql, database, optimization, survey, redundancy

I am looking for a solution to optimize my database model. The database manages **surveys**, you can add questions and answer to them. An entry is an answer to a survey and has answers for each question.

Here is the simplified schema:
[image]

**Is there a way to avoid the redundancy without removing the entries table ?**

*Keep in mind that my model includes more tables in order to provide more complex question's types. For now I couldn't provide the full schema.*

Comment: Thank you @AbstractChaos for fixing the schema.

Comment: Where is the redundancy (foreign keys are not redundancy, they exist precisely to avoid redundant information) ? IMHO, this structure is the only viable one.

Comment: @RandomSeed I agree with you but I feel uncomfortable with the double survey_id reference. the explicit one in the entries table and the implicit one in the answers table (from the question_id).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the feeling that either `ENTRIES.survey_id` or `QUESTIONS.survey_id` is redundant (probably because you see that one could deduce the one or the other through the `ANSWERS` entity).

In fact, `QUESTIONS` and `ENTRIES` entertain an identifying relationship with `SURVEYS` (an entry or a question may not exist without a corresponding survey). Formally speaking, their primary key *must* include a foreign key reference to their parent table `SURVEYS`:

```
CREATE TABLE SURVEYS (
    survey_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (survey_id)
);

CREATE TABLE QUESTIONS (
    question_id INT NOT NULL,
    survey_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (question_id, survey_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (survey_id) REFERENCES SURVEYS(survey_id)
);

CREATE TABLE ENTRIES (
    entry_id INT NOT NULL,
    survey_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (entry_id, survey_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (survey_id) REFERENCES SURVEYS(survey_id)
);
```

As an interesting consequence, your `ANSWERS` table should* actually *also* include `survey_id` in its foreign key references, because this field is part of the primary key of both `QUESTIONS` and `ENTRIES`:

```
CREATE TABLE ANSWERS (
    entry_id INT NOT NULL,
    survey_id INT NOT NULL,
    question_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (entry_id, survey_id, question_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (entry_id, survey_id)
        REFERENCES ENTRIES(entry_id, survey_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (question_id, survey_id)
        REFERENCES QUESTIONS(question_id, survey_id)
);
```

If it can help you letting go of the false impression that one `survey_id` field is redundant, consider that there may exist an entry with no answer (eg. when a new entry is created). In this situation, `ENTRIES.survey_id` is obviously required.

---

* Actually this extra field is *required* to model the constraint "an answer must relate to a question and an entry which both belong to the same survey".

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I was worried about the fact that from the answer I could (with join) access to `SURVEYS` by `QUESTIONS` and `ENTRIES`. I understood that I have no other choice. I am not really a fan of hybrid ID. I rather work with unique ID; controllers are easier to make. Thank you again for your explanation.

Comment: @QuentinWalter I didn't even realise that `ANSWERS.survey_id` is required when I first wrote my answer (see my edit). This is however a perfect illustration of the relevance of these "rules". You can drop the seemingly convoluted composite primary keys, but there is a tradeoff in terms of performance since you would need several additional `UNIQUE` constraints (and these constraints should really be considered redundant).

Comment: Thank you again for all your explanations. I was confused about those composite PK. I used to create DB with surrogate PK and FK (shame on me). Now I think I understood the way composite PK works. [Can you please give me your opinion on the full model?](http://quentinwalter.com/dev/survey_db_model.png) Some rules: `ITEM` contains the choice of each question, each item has an icon. `TYPE` defines the type of each question. An icon can belong to a category. A [question] type can have an icon.

Comment: @QuentinWalter I wrongly suggested that a relationship is identifying *if and only if* the relation is mandatory, and this is misleading. The reverse is not true: a mandatory relation may not be identifying. Whether a relationship is identifying is more a logical concept rather than a mechanical consequence. An Answer makes no sense on its own without a corresponding Question. But a Question without a Type still carries some meaning. The relations [Question > Type] and [Item > Icon] are probably not identifying.

Comment: Thank you for your advices, your explanations were really clear. I hesitated some times on these both relations and this is why I asked your opinion. I am glad that you noticed them too.